# Unittest failing due a diff on my proto, but diff looks the same

Tags: go

I'm working on an unittest that tests a function that returns a proto message. The test failed in one of the Proto fields, but I don't see any difference on the fields.

Here is my function:

```golang
 func (c *Client) contructInstanceRequest() *compute.Instance {
      prefix := "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/" + c.ProjectID
      sshKey := c.readSSHKey()

      instance := &compute.Instance{
          Name:           c.InstanceName,
          Description:    "compute sample instance",
          MinCpuPlatform: "Intel Cascade Lake",
          MachineType:    prefix + "/zones/" + c.Zone + "/machineTypes/c2-standard-4",
          CanIpForward:   true,
          Tags: &compute.Tags{
              Items: []string{
                  "http-server",
                  "https-server",
                  "eve-ng",
              },
          },
          Disks: []*compute.AttachedDisk{
              {
                  AutoDelete: true,
                  Boot:       true,
                  Type:       "PERSISTENT",
                  InitializeParams: &compute.AttachedDiskInitializeParams{
                      DiskName:    "my-root-" + c.InstanceName,
                      SourceImage: "projects/" + c.ProjectID + "/global/images/" + c.CustomEveNGImageName,
                      DiskType:    "projects/" + c.ProjectID + "/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-ssd",
                  },
              },
          },
          NetworkInterfaces: []*compute.NetworkInterface{
              {
                  AccessConfigs: []*compute.AccessConfig{
                      {
                          Type: "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
                          Name: "External NAT",
                      },
                  },
                  Network: prefix + "/global/networks/default",
              },
          },
          ServiceAccounts: []*compute.ServiceAccount{
              {
                  Email: "default",
                  Scopes: []string{
                      compute.DevstorageFullControlScope,
                      compute.ComputeScope,
                  },
              },
          },
          Metadata: &compute.Metadata{
              Kind: "compute#metadata",
              Items: []*compute.MetadataItems{
                  {
                      Key:   "ssh-keys",
                      Value: proto.String(c.SSHKeyUsername + ":" + string(sshKey)),
                  },
              },
          },
      }
      return instance

  }
```

##### Unittest

```
func TestConstructInstanceRequest(t *testing.T) {
      client, err := setup(t)
      if err != nil {
          t.Errorf("could not create a new goeve client, error: %v", err)
      }

      tests := []struct {
          name string
          zone string
          want *compute.Instance
      }{
          {
              name: "instance1",
              want: &compute.Instance{
                  Name:                   "instance1",
                  Description:            "compute sample instance",
                  MinCpuPlatform:         "Intel Cascade Lake",
                  LastSuspendedTimestamp: "",
                  MachineType:            "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testProject/zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/c2-standard-4",
                  CanIpForward:           true,
                  Tags: &compute.Tags{
                      Items: []string{
                          "http-server",
                          "https-server",
                          "eve-ng",
                      },
                  },
                  Disks: []*compute.AttachedDisk{
                      {
                          AutoDelete: true,
                          Boot:       true,
                          Type:       "PERSISTENT",
                          InitializeParams: &compute.AttachedDiskInitializeParams{
                              DiskName:    "my-root-instance1",
                              SourceImage: "projects/testProject/global/images/test-eve-ng",
                              DiskType:    "projects/testProject/zones/us-central1-a/diskTypes/pd-ssd",
                          },
                      },
                  },
                  NetworkInterfaces: []*compute.NetworkInterface{
                      {
                          AccessConfigs: []*compute.AccessConfig{
                              {
                                  Type: "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
                                  Name: "External NAT",
                              },
                          },
                          Network: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testProject/global/networks/default",
                      },
                  },
                  ServiceAccounts: []*compute.ServiceAccount{
                      {
                          Email: "default",
                          Scopes: []string{
                              compute.DevstorageFullControlScope,
                              compute.ComputeScope,
                          },
                      },
                  },
                  Metadata: &compute.Metadata{
                      Kind:            "compute#metadata",
                      ForceSendFields: nil,
                      NullFields:      nil,
                      Items: []*compute.MetadataItems{
                          {
                              Key:   "ssh-keys",
                              Value: proto.String("eve:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDIn5Zc9uF4qO8c3e0bxL2jOfPckeuzS56aATA/5aj/Cjx/xiZF+z7t8k5dIg4qX2KJR162iI  NDnef0XnTPsPs6q6rlVY1ZztZ6OcjqR7bhjfCNVd3s1+zY31uIj3WuorcRzy29yYZUSS7ZTUDXj2ZY5aGDsB47+Cybx/xVsedV83hATB05kQOKFpvRUKdnrnRxjyliwE9C2PbFWViK7sJk"),
                          },
                      },
                  },
              },
          },
      }

      for _, tc := range tests {
          got := client.contructInstanceRequest()
          if diff := cmp.Diff(tc.want.Metadata.Items, got.Metadata.Items); diff != "" {
              t.Errorf("contructInstanceRequest() returned unexpected diff (-want +got):\n%s", diff)
          }

      }
  }
```

I'm encountering the issue under `ssh-keys` value.

Here is the `diff` output:

```
go test
--- FAIL: TestConstructInstanceRequest (0.00s)
    goeve_test.go:150: contructInstanceRequest() returned unexpected diff (-want +got):
          []*compute.MetadataItems{
                &{
                        Key:             "ssh-keys",
        -               Value:           &"eve:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDIn5Zc9uF4qO8c3e0bxL2jOfPckeuzS56aATA/5aj/Cjx/xiZF+z7t8k5dIg4qX2KJR162iINDnef0XnTPsPs6q6rlVY1ZztZ6OcjqR7bhjfCNVd3s1+zY31uIj3WuorcRzy29yYZUSS7ZTUDXj2ZY5aGDsB47+Cybx/xVsedV83hATB05kQOKFpvRUKdnrnRxjyliwE9C2PbFWViK7sJk",
        +               Value:           &"eve:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDIn5Zc9uF4qO8c3e0bxL2jOfPckeuzS56aATA/5aj/Cjx/xiZF+z7t8k5dIg4qX2KJR162iINDnef0XnTPsPs6q6rlVY1ZztZ6OcjqR7bhjfCNVd3s1+zY31uIj3WuorcRzy29yYZUSS7ZTUDXj2ZY5aGDsB47+Cybx/xVsedV83hATB05kQOKFpvRUKdnrnRxjyliwE9C2PbFWViK7sJk"...,
                        ForceSendFields: nil,
                        NullFields:      nil,
                },
          }
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    go-eve/goeve    0.007s
```

As you can see, there is no difference in the `ssh-keys` value. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong and I will appreciate if someone can take a look at this. Thanks

Comment: proto.String returns a pointer. And as you can see in the test output there's an `&` prepended to the string value. two pointers are equal if their memory address is equal. The pointed-to value does not play a role

Comment: Besides what @blackgreen already mentioned, it looks like you could define a Transformer on `*string` that returns a memoized copy, to get string equality, or (simpler) a Comparer on `*string`. See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Comparer

Comment: I might simplify the question, because I'm showing that I want to compare the `tc.want.Metadata.Items vs got.Metadata.Items`, but in reality I want to compare `tc.want vs got`. I might have to split the test if I don't find a solution to test the entire struct.

Answer (score 1):

I print both value. `tc.want.Metadata.Items[0].Value` and `got.Metadata.Items[0].Value` and saw that yes there was a diff. I was missing almost half of the strings.